# Jquery stop fadeOut animation on Mouseleave

Tags: jquery, fadeout

Is there a way to stop an `fadeOut()` animation on `mouseleave` in jQuery? 
I want the script to work like:

- 1: When user mouse over text, show a div
- 2: When user mouse out of    text hide the div, but if the user
  instead hover over container, the    div must continue showing!

This is what i'm working at:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $('.this').hover(function(){
        $('#container').fadeIn(200);
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        setTimeout(function () {
        $('#container').fadeOut(200);
    }, 1000);
    })

    $('#container').hover(function(){
        $('#container').stop().show();
    })

});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y36ta/)

Comment: Why do you have the setTimeout?  You want a delayed fade on mouseleave?

Comment: if container is faded out then how it will get the hover event?

Comment: Jai-> That's a good question. What is the best way to make that working? :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/y36ta/6/

```
var $container = $('#container');

$('.this').on('mouseover', function(){
    $container.stop(true).fadeIn(200);
}).on('mouseleave', function(){
    $container.stop(true).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
})

$container.on('mouseenter', function(){
    $(this).stop(true).clearQueue().show();
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).delay(200).fadeOut(200);
});
```

Update: use `.on()` to bind handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.this').hover(function () {
        $('#container').fadeIn(200);
    });
    $('.this').mouseleave(function (e) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            if ($('#container:hover').length != 1) $('#container').fadeOut(200);
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y36ta/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

[Heres a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KEmCG/10/). check it out, I think it's what you need.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').hover(function() {
          $('.this').stop().fadeTo(200, 1, function(){
               $('.this').fadeTo(800, 0.1);
          });
    }, function() {
          $('.this').stop().fadeTo(200, 0.1);
    });
});
```

hope it helps